# CAKEPHP 3 after save success close date in database is not null, it has todays value

Tags: mysql, orm, cakephp-3.0

I have the input field

```
echo $this->Form->input('close_date',['empty' => true, 'default' => '']);
```

with validation rules ..

```
 $validator->add('close_date', 'valid', ['rule' => 'date'])->allowEmpty('close_date');
```

the output of $this->request->data before :

```
$ticket = $this->Tickets->patchEntity($ticket, $this->request->data);
```

is

```
['close_date' => [
        'day' => '',
        'month' => '',
        'year' => ''
    ]]
```

but after save success close date in database is not null, it has todays value ....

in MySql table field close_date is type DATE default NULL

what am i missing here ...  i want this field to continue NULL why is cake saving with todays date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAICT the datetime type is not able to marshall empty date array structures into null values yet. You may want to report this over [**at github**](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues), it might be worth adding support for this to the core.

As a (temporary) workaround you could for example use [**the `Model.beforeMarshal` event/callback**](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/table-objects.html#beforemarshal) and manually set the property to `null` in case the date array is empty, something like:

```php
public function beforeMarshal(Event $event, \ArrayObject $data, \ArrayObject $options)
{
    if (
        isset($data['close_date']) &&
        is_array($data['close_date']) &&
        !array_filter($data['close_date'])
    ) {
        $data['close_date'] = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: i was going to report at github but they are already into it , https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/pull/5821